# PhantomJS: Nested tables insert whitespace between rows

Tags: html, phantomjs, whitespace

I have following HTML code:
https://gist.github.com/enlilcz/4c8baf50f35838ed5bb2

And phantomJs inserts this whitespace:

[image]

Almost no styles is on page, and I believe this problem is not about styles.
Problem is in nested tables - there is table in table.
When is removed parent table - removed lines 23-26 and 230-233 in HTML
and whitespace just dissapear.

PhantomJs settings is:

```
{
  outputFormat: "pdf",
  html: "myHTML",
  version: 2,
  phantomParams: {
    paperSize: {
      format: "A4",
      margin: "0px"
    }
  }
}
```

And when I substitute paperSize to

```
viewportSize: {
   'width': 2750, // or any other  dimensions
   'height': 3850
}
```

it also starts to work, but I need to use paperSize...

Does anyone knows where is the problem?

Comment: Please add a reduced version of your markup to the question.

Comment: Try to retrieve the computed style of some of the elements and see which one is the culprit. Then devise a reset style add put it into your page before making the screenshot.